# Show that there cannot be a analytic function on $B(0,1)$ s.t if $|z|\to 1$, $|f(z)|\to \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there cannot be a analytic function on $B(0,1)$ s.t if $|z|\to 1$, $|f(z)|\to \infty$.

I saw a proof on here but I dont quite understand it.

[Does there exist a function which is holomorphic on the open unit disc but goes to infinity on the boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156837/does-there-exist-a-function-which-is-holomorphic-on-the-open-unit-disc-but-goes)

The trick is to consider $1/f(z)$. Since then if $|z|\to 1$ then $1/f(z)\to 0$ and so we can continuously extend $1/f(z)$ to the closed unit ball to be zero on the boundary. Now we are done if we can extend $1/f(z)$ to be holomorphic in  the closed unit ball by maximum modulus principle. However, to do so, i need $f(z)$ to have finite zeroes in the unit ball which I cannot seem to prove. I can prove it has finite zeros if $f(z)$ was holomorphic on a compact set. But an open ball is not compact and so $f$ could have infinite zeroes, at least i think. Could someone fill in the details for me here?

Comment: It's been elaborated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468895/does-there-exist-a-holomorphic-function-with-the-following-property).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah yes, I must have missed that, thank you very much

Comment: @DanielFischer: Any reason not to close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @MartinR I voted to close

Comment: @MartinR In case that didn't clarify things completely, I wanted to leave the opportunity to explain how it didn't. (Yes, that's also possible when it's marked as duplicate, but I find it friendlier to wait a little bit.)

Comment: note that the result is true if $|f| \to \infty$ almost everywhere on the boundary (and with non-tangential limits only - namely limits from within a triangle inside the dsc with a vertex at a boundary point  - rather than unrestricted ones

Comment: In fact there is no holomorphic function in the disc that has radial limit $\infty$ everywhere in an arc of positive length on the boundary.